# c# Regex remove words of less than 3 letters?

Tags: c#, regex

Any ideas on the regex need to remove words of 3 letters or less? So it would find "ii it was bbb cat rat hat" etc but not "four, three, twos".

Comment: "two" has three letters

Comment: Should the words 'bbb', 'cat', 'rat', and 'hat' be removed? Those words are not less than 3 letters long.

Comment: I'd argue that you should not use regexes here, never use a regex when three simple lines of code can do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and throw a non-regex solution at you:

```
public static string StripWordsWithLessThanXLetters(string input, int x)
{
    var inputElements = input.Split(' ');
    var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var element in inputElements)
    {
        if (element.Length >= x)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append(element + " ");
        }
    }
    return resultBuilder.ToString().Trim();
}
```

This is more verbose than the other solutions, but I think the performance cost of using the Linq solution might outweigh its net benefit, and a regex incur the same costs (potentially with more complexity to maintenance.)

Comment: Yeah probably shouldn't use regex for this :S . Thanks for the help . and thanks to all for the other solutions.

Comment: The performance difference between this and a Linq selection is negligible. I wrote a quick benchmark of 1 million iterations over this input string "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten". The for loop / StringBuilder method took 2.4891901 seconds, the Linq selection method took 2.4480243 seconds.

Comment: Interestingly, the regex solution took 1.4886646 seconds :s

Comment: @MattDavey: Granted, but this method is far from a complete model (not exactly a 'solution',) no doubt it will be updated with various alterations to account for any specific requirements, and I would hazard a guess to say the more complex the Linq query gets, the longer it would take in comparison - and that's just a guess, mind you, based on my experience of Linq being an amazingly convenient tool but not a terribly efficient one. And the efficiency of regex doesn't concern me so much as its ghastly ugliness does.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment I find it interesting that your experience of Linq has left you doubting its performance, I've always been consistently amazed by its efficiency! :)

Comment: @MattDavey: Also, that's a little funny, since I just got the following results: loop: `00:00:00.0008252`, `00:00:00.0009540`, `00:00:00.0005613`. Linq: `00:00:00.0025795`, `00:00:00.0016150`, `00:00:00.0017305`.

Comment: LINQ is much, much faster than a lot of people think. Every task is different, but you can usually expect the overhead to be on the order of 15-20%, and often it's much less than that. Meanwhile, it can take a fraction of the time to code. Remember the old saying about premature optimization.

Comment: @MattDavey: As for million/s of iterations: loop:`00:00:20.7630990`. Linq: `00:00:32.7496051`.

Comment: Can't think why your benchmark might have given such different results.. were you writing something to the console on each iteration by any chance?

Comment: @MattDavey: I'm not so naive: these tests did nothing but loop and call the appropriate method. Printing of the `Stopwatch.Elapsed` occurring once, after the fact.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment you seem to be a little over-sensetive about this. I wasn't implying that your answer was innacurate or inappropriate, I was merely pointing out that Linq performance is more than acceptable in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @MattDavey: And I don't disagree with that, I use it daily and don't intend to stop - my solution was merely another way to skin this cat, with reasons as to why one _might_ consider it.

Answer (score 9):

Regex to match words of length 1 to 3 would be `\b\w{1,3}\b`, replace these matches with empty string.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\b\w{1,3}\b");
var result = re.Replace(input, "");
```

To also remove double spaces you could use:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\s*\b\w{1,3}\b\s*");
var result = re.Replace(input, " ");
```

(Altho it will leave a space at the beginning/end of string.)

Answer (score 7):

Don't necessarily need a regex for this, it can be done with a simple linq selection.

```
string[] words = inputString.Split(' ');

var longWords = words.Where(x => x.Length > 3);

string outputString = String.Join(" ", longWords.ToArray());
```

Hell you could even do it in one line of code:

```
outputString = String.Join(" ", inputString.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 3).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string qText = "Long or not long sample text";
var inputWords = qText.Split(' ').ToList();
var rem = (from c in inputWords
           where c.Length > 3
           select c).ToList();
```

Comment: Please add some text/description to improve your anser

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is an issue, here's another implementation that doesn't involve regex nor linq.

It's about 20% to 25% faster than other solutions

```
public static string StripWordsByLength(this string str, int minLength)
{
    bool addSpace = false;
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string word in str.Split(' '))
    {
        if (word.Length >= minLength)
        {
            if (addSpace)
                resultBuilder.Append(' ');
            else
                addSpace = true;

            resultBuilder.Append(word);
        }
    }
    return resultBuilder.ToString();
}
```